# Android Studio - can malware embed rogue code that displays ads?

Tags: android, android-webview

A new version of my app (using WebView) was rejected by Google play stating that it shows rogues ads - attached the screenshots shared by google.

[image]
My app is a small app - does not have any ads and I have developed it.

None of the testers have identified the issue. Nor did the earlier version face this issue.

I am interested to know if a rogue code be embedded in my App by virus/trojan/malware without me knowing? Or has the Google reviewer made a mistake?

Comment: are you using any webview ?

Comment: @ManoharReddy - Yes I am using webview.

Comment: May be the site which you are opening in webview is showing ads .

Comment: @ManoharReddy - The webview only opens local html files. There are 3-4 external links but they open in separate browser. The js libraries are downloaded from CDN. As you can see in attached image the ad pops-up after the app is closed (and does not share screen with the app).

Comment: If you are displaying local html files then do not enable javascript on webview . Websites can display full screen ads too also check if any of the dependencies you added are displaying ads . I cannot think of any other possible way .

Comment: @ManoharReddy Thax for reply. I need Javascript as thats key part in webview. (i) Can a webview page put a full banner ad even if the app is CLOSED (as shown in the attached image) - or would such a event be trigerred by native code? (ii) Could the reviewers browser be at fault - maybe some adons or something else?